# Pytorch-tutorial: Strange input argument in class definition

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm reading through some pytorch tutorials. Below is the definition of a residual block. However in the `forward` method each function handle only takes one argument `out` while in the `__init__` function these functions have different number of input arguments:

```
# Residual Block
class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, stride=1, downsample=None):
        super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = conv3x3(in_channels, out_channels, stride)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv2 = conv3x3(out_channels, out_channels)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.downsample = downsample

    def forward(self, x):
        residual = x
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        if self.downsample:
            residual = self.downsample(x)
        out += residual
        out = self.relu(out)
        return out
```

Does anyone know how this works?
Is it a standard python class inheritance feature or is this specific to pytorch?

Comment: In `__init__`, they are function builder, for example, `conv3x3(in_channels, out_channels, stride)` returns a function which is assigned to `self.conv1`. In `forward`, you are calling these functions built in `__init__`.

Comment: Yes, but `conv3x3` expects two arguments in `__init__` whereas in `forward it is called with only one argument  (`x`)

Comment: `conv3x3` is a function which expects two arguments, but, it can returns another function which just expects one argument. Is it explicit enough? Or I should write an answer with examples?

Comment: Ahh I think I get what you mean. Well thanks! If you put your answer below I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you define the layer in the init function, which means the parameters. In the forward function you only input the data that needs to be processed with the predefined settings from init. The nn.whatever builds a function with the settings you pass to it. Then this function can be used in forward and this function only takes one argument.

Answer (score 0):

You define different layers of your network architecture in the constructor of the class (`__init__` function). Essentially, when you create an instance of different layers, you initialize them with your settings parameters.

For example, when you declare the first convolution layer, `self.conv1`, you give the parameters required to initialize the layer. In the forward function, you just simply call the layers with the input to get the corresponding output. For example, in `out = self.conv2(out)`, you take the output of the previous layer and give it as an input the next `self.conv2` layer.

Please note, during initialization, you give information to the layer that what kind/shape of input will be provided to that layer. For example, you tell the first convolution layer that what will be number of input and output channels in your input. In the forward method, you just need to pass the input, that's it.